# Custom sorting function bottleneck

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to sort big array using actionscript 3.

The problem is that i have to use custom sorting function which is painfully slow and leads to flash plugin crash.

Below is a sample code for custom function used to sort array by length of its members:

```
            private function sortByLength():int {
                var x:int = arguments[0].length;
                var y:int = arguments[1].length;
                if (x > y){
                    return 1;                       
                }else if (x < y){
                    return -1;
                }else{
                    return 0;
                }
             }
```

Which is called like this:

```
    var txt:Array = ["abcde","ab","abc","a"];
    txt.sort(sortByLength);
```

---

Please advise me how can this be done faster ?

How to change application logic to avoid Flash plugin crashes during sorting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use strong typing whenever possible, here tell your function that you are waiting two strings.

you could rewrite your function in two way one fastest than the other if you know that all your element are not null:

```
function sortByLength(a:String, b:String):int {
    return a.length-b.length // fastest way not comparison
}
```

and if you can have null check for it (this one will put null in front of all element):

```
 function sortByLengthWithNull(a:String, b:String):int {
     if (a==null) return -1
     if (b==null) return 1
     return a.length-b.length
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I certainly accept it. One question however is unanswered - how to perform greedy computations in Flash without hanging it ? For example your function will fail on arrays having 200000+ members. How to change application logic to avoid Flash plugin crashes during CPU intensive tasks (like sorting big arrays) ?

Comment: @Eugeny89 Don't guess but try ;) It will works faster because : you eliminate indice array access of arguments[], you eliminate branching that is costly. Now if you test it with not so much data you will not see difference.

Comment: @Eugeny89 A quick test with enough data show that it's 3x-4x faster

Comment: @Patrick,hm!!!! That's very interesting! thank you for pointing out!.... already upvoted on your post

Comment: @Termos as said @alecme you have to break your work into chunk to not freeze the UI. With the next upcomming version of the flash player , using webworker like, hope this extra work will be useless :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need super-fast sorting, then it might be worthwhile not using an array at all and instead using a linked-list. There are different advantages to each. Primarily, with a linked-list, index-access is slow, while iterating through the list is fast, and linked-lists are not native to AS3 so you'll have to roll your own.

On the upside, you may well be able to use some of Polygonal Labs' code: http://lab.polygonal.de/as3ds/.

Sorting is very, very fast for nearly-sorted data with a linked list, as this article discusses: http://lab.polygonal.de/2007/11/26/data-structures-more-on-linked-lists/.

This solution gives you lots more work, but will eventually give you lots more sort-speed too.

Hope this helps.

-- additional --

I noticed your question in the comments of another answer about "One question however is unanswered - how to perform greedy computations in Flash without hanging it?"

For this, essentially the answer is to break your computation over multiple frames, something like this:

```
public function sort():void
{
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, iterateSort);
}

private function iterateSort():void
{
    var time:int = getTimer() + TARGET_MILLISECONDS_PER_FRAME;
    var isFinished:Boolean = false;

    while (!isFinished && getTimer() < time)
        isFinished = continueSort();

    if (isFinished)
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, iterateSort);
}

function continueSort():Boolean
{
    ... implement an 'atom of sort' here, whatever that means ...
}
```

Comment: To locate a length look up is O(n) and scales linear, as linked lists don't normally cache the length - although it does seem that polygonal does every effort to try and keep it in sync. So if he has 20000+ elements he would need to go from 0-20000+ elements to find the length.

Answer (score 1):

`sortByLength` should have two parameters, shouldn't it? I guess that's what you mean by the `arguments` array...

This looks fine to me, unless `arguments` is not a local variable, but instead a member variable, and you're just looking at its `[0]` and `[1]` elements on each function call. That would at least produce undesired results.

Comment: I am new to AS3 but as far as i know it works like that: custom function is called to check every array element. Each time 2 array elements are compared so arguments[0] and arguments[1] are array elements being compared

Comment: Looking at the Array documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sort()), it mentions that the sort function should have two arguments, and I've always done it that way without problems. I don't know if it has anything to do with this particular issue though.